# CSS code position -> p selector and footer p selector

Tags: html, css

I was writing CSS code while i was doing an exercise about descendent selectors and then this i really start thinking that what about if we put our footer p selector on the top of our p selector in the css code? (firstly i had the footer p selector at the end), i tried and i did't expect the result,  i thought that this footer p selector declarations would be overwritten by the p declarations, because the p inside the footer still a p element, why does't this happen????? can you explain please, thanks

[code example, expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eacHJ.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is because of "specificity" i.e. the rules that dictate which selectors win when more than one of them can apply.

In short `footer p` is more "specific" than just `p`. So it's size property "wins" between the two.

The rules to calculate specificity involve counting up each component (classes, ids, tagnames, etc) of the complex selector and comparing their counts, with each type of component trumping others along a certain hierarchy.

[image]

Read more: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Your selectors are `p = 0,0,0,1` and `footer p = 0,0,0,2` The one with the higher left-most, non-zero number wins in your case `footer p`

Comment: OK, i understand it now, thanks WillD !!!

Answer (score 0):

The selector

“footer p” has higher specificity than the “p” selector that’s why it will overtake and apply the styles nevertheless its order. Check for css specificity here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity